# semop: Numerical result out of range

Tags: posix, multiprocessing

When I was trying XSI IPC semaphore, I used it in the way that one process kept incrementing the semaphore, and another process kept doing the reverse, both of which set the flag of SEM_UNDO.
Finally the trivial program ended with an error of: semop: Numerical result out of range.
I guess it's caused by the large adjustment value. Is there any solution to this problem, if I don't give up the SEM_UNDO flag?

Comment: suffering with the same problem now.. :)